# Regex extract number between characters

Tags: regex, numbers, extract

I have a returned string formatted as below:

```
PR ER 

89

>
```

from which the number can be extracted by using `\n(\d+)`, but sometimes it returns:

```
23 PR P 10000>
```

Or, it could be something like:

```
23

PR P

10000

>
```

In these scenarios, how can I extract the number `10000` between `PR` and `>`?

Comment: What regex engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
\d+(?=\s*>)
```

It looks for any sequence of digits followed by any number of whitespaces and a '>'

Answer (score 0):

## For java if you need

```
String str = "23 PR P 10000>";
    Pattern reg = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
    Matcher m = reg.matcher(str);
    while (m.find()){
        System.out.println("group : " + m. group() + " - start :" + m.start() + " - end :" + m.end());
    }
```

Comment: The code might he helpful for the OP but can you explain the answer a bit so others who are missing out will know what it goes and how it solves OP's question?

Comment: You should read and practice more to know about regular expression here
[link](https://regexone.com/), hope it will help you

Comment: I didnt mean it for myself but for users who will search for answers and all they see is code.

Answer (score 0):

i might just answer this myself

```
\d+\n>
```

worked!
thanks all

Comment: your answer doesn't match either of the examples you provided with the question. It requires a single newline between the number and the '>' character. It also captures the '>' character, which is incorrect according to your explanation. The answer I provided before you posted your answer, matches your examples and only captures the target number.

Comment: guess the one i received is a line feed instead of carriage return, somehow it is happy